# How do I check if sound card is in use and, if possible, which process is using it?

Tags: osx, audio, devices

I want to know if a program is using my sound card without my knowledge. I thought about building a program that uses low-level device driver code to do the trick, but am now interested in seeing if I can use a command-line tool.

Comment: `fuser /dev/audio` (or whatever your system's audio devices are)

Comment: @RickyBeam Will you please put that in an answer? That way, I can "accept" it and you can earn reps.

Answer (score 0):

`fuser /dev/audio` (or whatever devices and paths there are to your OS's sound device(s))

Comment: Except that on Mac OS X there is no device file for audio devices... The basic API for sound on Mac OS X is CoreAudio, which doesn't use traditional device files.

Comment: No matter how much API is stacked on it, one must still open a device file to talk to a device. (unless they've wired to syscalls or IPC to an "audio daemon", but I've not seen anyone do that since Ultrix.)

Comment: Have you had a look on a Mac? Programs outputting sound have no devices open other than `/dev/null` and `/dev/random`, and even the `coreaudiod` daemon only has `/dev/null` and `/dev/random` open. There's nothing in `/dev` corresponding to an audio device at all (and no corresponding device node anywhere else either).

Comment: Not one running coreaudio. moonman wanted it as an answer, so I made it answer. Take it up with him.